# Precise Search with MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, search

Lets suppose we have one table with column id, post_text.

And we have data in it as :

**id  post_text**

1. Rent hotel Mohali near bus stop.
2. Hotel mohali
3. Rent hotel Delhi
4. Rent hotel Lima , lower prices.

lets suppose I want to search with word "Rent mohali" than I should get only first result.
i.e
id  post_text

1. Rent hotel Mohali near bus stop.

because it both word rent and mohali is present in it.

@mysql, @java, @searching ,@precise search

Comment: Divide your search phrase to separate words. Test the values against each word. Group, count the amount of matches. Compare with the amount of words in the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL and you'd like to use dynamic searching, you can use Full-Text feature which is more powerful than using the LIKE but be aware that you have to change the structure of you database to support searching index. Using the Full-Text, in addition to getting the result by semantic similarity, it offers more options to filter the query.

Like keyword in the other hand is not powerful and not dynamic but you don't have to change your database structure with indexes and nature language mode. If you follow that way, you have to find a way to split into multiple likes to try to find two things in one search.